# Erlangen program for "network geometry"

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gr.group-theory, mg.metric-geometry, lie-groups, symmetry

The subject of network geometry (Boguna et al., Network Geometry,
Nature Reviews Physics 2021) looks at "geometric aspects" of complex networks.

This is about studying a metric on the nodes, though can involve diffusion geometry, and fractal geometry as well.

Can one work with an "Erlangen program" for a complex network? Though each node is not the same given the high heterogeneity of the network (they are not in a "homogeneous space"), there is some "statistical symmetry", given the complex networks can be naturally embedded in hyperbolic space (D. Krioukov,
Clustering Implies Geometry in Networks, Phys. Rev. Lett. 2016).

I am basically trying to understand if network geometry, in this sense, can be thought of in terms of group theory and projective geometry.

Comment: Graphs, geometry and symmetry interact very strongly in the area of geometric group theory, usually using the natural path metric on the graph. I don't know if that fits into the framework of "network geometry".

Comment: Ok very interesting. So the automorphism group of the graph would then have a geometric structure?

Comment: Not usually the full automorphism group; geometric group theory is primarily concerned with discrete groups acting geometrically on graphs. But there are some strands where the discrete group is thought of as a lattice in the full automorphism group. It’s a big subject, so hard to summarise, but if you want an overview you could do worse than look at the recent book “Office hours with a geometric group theorist”.